# Изменить background пунктов меню при переходе на внутреннюю страницу

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть пункты меню в `heder`, они имеют прозрачный `background`. При переходе на внутреннюю страницу надо поменять `background` этих пунктов меню но только на определённой внутренней странице(не на всех страницах). Подскажите, пжл., как это можно сделать на чистом `css`? Как-то находил решение, где используется `"#страница_о_нас.html"` в файле `style.css` для изменения стили блока для страницы `"#страница_о_нас.html"`.
https://jsfiddle.net/4m7y0a3y/4/

Comment: Приведите ваш код.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4m7y0a3y/

Comment: @AGS17 , а теперь при переходе на <button>Sign Up</button> background для приведённых двух buttons должен стать green. (P.S.: переходы осуществляются с помощью node.js). Спс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В css есть псевдокласс `:target`. Работает он так. На на странице у вас есть элемент с неким id. Допустим такой код в `index.html`:

```
<a href="#someid">Show me</a>
<p id="someid">Text</p>
```

И такой css:

```
#someid {
   color: red;
}
#someid:target {
   color: green;
}
```

При нажатии на ссылку, вы будете перемещены на ту же самую страницу, в то ее место где находится `<p id="someid">Text</p>`. При этом сам текст, ранее бывший красным, станет зеленым, а в адресной строке браузера будет значится `index.html#someid`.

В целом можно сделать рабочий вариант того что вы хотите, но побочные эффекты - скачки по странице и ее перезагрузка убивают все преимущества простоты css.

Предлагаю подумать над решением на js, либо php.